# Moving multiple security certificates from server to server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-20.04

I have moved a site from an ISP to a private server and need to move my SSL certs over.
However, the ISP gave me 4 certs for the site in question, so I am unsure of the match of three of the four files, as well as confused about why I have four:

```
AAACertificateServices.crt   
[THE DOMAIN I AM MOVING]_com.crt
SectigoRSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt   
USERTrustRSAAAACA.crt
```

Spending time to research the procedure of installing the certs for a site up and running on Ubuntu 20.04 with Apache2, all the online docs I found will have me edit the virtual host block of the Apache2 site conf file thusly:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.x.x:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/[THE DOMAIN I AM MOVING]
    ServerName [THE DOMAIN I AM MOVING]
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/[THE DOMAIN I AM MOVING]_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/privatekey.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/intermediate.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

There is one obvious .crt file that matches here, but I am not sure of the placement of two others, and entirely unsure why I received 4 files instead of 3.

So, I have a couple of questions:

- Why the forth file?
- Which two of the remaining three are the privatekey and intermediate files?
- Is there a standard way to identify the purpose of each file?

Comment: Some of those certs are almost certainly intermediate CA authorities. Because I'm not familiar with the chains for those CAs I would have to look at the certs themselves to figure out how the chain connects together. You can figure it out yourself by using an appropriate tool, for example `openssl x509 -in xxxx.cert -text -noout`. The issuer of YOUR DOMAIN.crt is the next cert in the chain, then the issuer of that cert is next, and so on. One of those may be a root certificate in which case the issue and subject names will be identical. You may exclude that one from the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a number of combinations, but cannot get these files to work. The ISP that originated the certs is no help, as they have WHM and cPanels that make this an easier task, but my server does not have either so I am stuck with manual entries.
I have successfully installed a Comodo cert for one of two sites I have on my private server, so I am OK for now using that one, but it remains a mystery and a problem: not being able to EASILY transfer certs from a shared server to a private server.
I will continue the effort and post any positive results.
So, the "answer" here is: This operation is difficult and there is no easy solution I have found, to date.